# HTML: cannot open client e-mail app

Tags: html, email

for some reason, the following code doesn't work. I don't understand where the issue is. I just want to open a client e-mail app to send an e-mail.

```
<a href="mailto:enter-friend@address-here.com?subject=My Website&amp;body=This e-mail has been sent to inform you about my website website: www.mywebsite.com">Send an email to a friend</a>
```

- **Safari** visits the page "mailto:enter-friend@address-here.com?subject=Pa0Website&body=This%20e-mail%20has%20been%20sent%20to%20inform%20you%20about%20%20website:%20"
- **Chrome** doesn't do anything

I haven't tested on other browsers so far.

Thanks

Comment: have you tested this on a different machine? I just tested, it started the email client for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get to decide how the client deals with a mailto link.  Each user/browser can do what it wants with those links.  For instance, I have my chrome setup to open GMail when I click mailto links.  Apparently you have yours setup to not do anything.  Here's a random link running down how to do something like this on your system - http://bnee.com/2008/09/make-mailto-links-open-in-gmail-in-google-chrome-browser-windows-xp-and-vista/

Comment: but then is "mailto:" parameter quite unreliable ?

I mean, are default browser configurations working with it, or not ?

Comment: Yeah, they really should be.  I would say 99% of users and browsers have it configured to work as expected....

Comment: ok thanks, one more thing.. is the code above working for you ?

Comment: Yep, works fine for me: IE8/Windows -> opens Outlook.  In Chrome/Ubuntu -> opens a Gmail window.